# Custom controls and the VS Toolbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio, custom-controls, toolbar

I wonder what can be a cause for the non-apparition of custom/user controls in the Visual Studio Toolbar.

Thanks.

I have a solution with some projects and a lot of custom controls. Normally, these controls should appear in the toolbar automatically after the solution (re)build...
(I use VS2005, but this problem appears also in 2008)

Comment: I'm not sure if they should appear automatically.

Comment: @Slavo: In 2005 and 2008, I believe they do by default. At least, that was my last experience when doing a WinForms app with a lot of user controls.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Windows Form Designer -> General -> AutoToolboxPopulate

Set that to true.

(Visual Studio 2005)

Note: The current solution must be closed and reopened for the setting to take place (in case you don't read the description.)